# There are seats for 40 people, 8 rows 5 seats each row. M, A, W, E, and J arrive first.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The question asks "How many arrangements are there of seating if M and J sit together in front row and other 3 sit together in one of the other rows"

**My attempt:**

First I found the number of ways arranging M and J in the first row- 4 x 2! = 8 ways

Then I found number of ways of arranging the 3 others - 3 x 3! x 7C1 = 126 ways

I added the ways together to get 126 + 8 = 134 ways of seating

However the correct answer states that there are 1008 ways ( 8 x 126)

Why are 8 and 126 multiplied instead of sum?

Comment: It is the multiplication principle. For each arrangement of M&J in the first row, there are $126$ different arrangements for other three people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [multiplicative principle](https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_counting-addmult.html), which states that if an event $A$ can occur in $n$ ways, and for each possibility of $A$ an event $B$ can happen in $m$ ways, then events $A$ and $B$ can occur in $n \times m$ ways.

You can think of it this way: you know that the number of ways $M$ and $J$ can sit together at the front row is
$$\binom{4}{1}\cdot 2! = 8. $$
For *each* of these ways, the others ($A,W$ and $E$) can pick seats in
$$\binom{7}{1}\cdot \binom{3}{1}\cdot 3! = 126$$
ways. The key here is the *for each*. So consider a specific seating arrangement for $M$ and $J$:

$$\Huge \circ  \circ  \circ \small \ \  M \ \ \ J$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$

For this choice, $A,W$ and $E$ can pick seats in 126 ways. Now consider another specific seating for $M$ and $J$:
$$\Huge \circ \circ \small \ \ M \ \ \  J \ \ \Huge \circ $$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$
$$\Huge \circ \circ \circ \circ \circ$$

Once $M$ and $J$ have sat down, $A,W$ and $E$ can still pick seats in 126 ways. So, given these two starting positions, we have now found $126 + 126 = 252$ ways to seat everyone. If you continue with this logic, you will find that for each of the $8$ seating positions for $M$ and $J$, there are $126$ ways for the other to sit, so we end up with a total of
$$126 \cdot 8 = 1008$$
for all of them to sit.